# Real time Pitch Change while recording audio with AVAudioRecorder

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to achieve functionality in which I can record a video and apply the effect over it in Real-time like an alien. So that when I play it, will sound like the alien.

I have already achieved that I can change the pitch of the audio after recording the audio but now want to do it while recording the audio.

Here is code for Recording audio with its settings.

```
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];

NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                AVSampleRateKey,
                                nil];
NSError *error = nil;

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

_audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                  initWithURL:soundFileURL
                  settings:recordSettings
                  error:&error];

_audioRecorder.delegate = self;
_audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;


if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    [_audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureaudiodataoutput) instead of `AVAudioRecorder`, it allows you to handle audio data while it's being recorded:

```
_captureAudioDataOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
[_captureAudioDataOutput setAudioSettings:recordSettings];
[_captureAudioDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_dispatchQueue];
```

You need a [`AVCaptureSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession) and `self` must provide the function [`captureOutput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureaudiodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1386039-captureoutput).

In `captureOutput` you can use the code you already have to change the audio pitch.

Comment: @ChandniSanghani Comments are not for questions. If you have a new question, post it as new question.

Comment: I already added new questions but no one is answering for the same. My new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68602131/error-in-processing-audio-file-with-proper-format-and-data